# Changing the bootstrap border color to a custom hex color?

Tags: html, css, border, bootstrap-5

Let me preface this question by stating that I am quite new to web design, so I suspect the question might have an easy answer I didn't yet spot. In my current project, I seek to create a div with a colored border using bootstrap. Specifically, I want the border to use a specified hex color (say: `#cc6666`). While some [guidance on border coloring](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/borders/) can be found on the bootstrap website, the options seem to be limited to preserts (such as `border-primary` or `border-dark`), seemingly without a straightforward option to define a custom color.

**Question**: Is there a straightforward option to use a custom hex color for bootstrap borders?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="border rounded border-primary">
  <prompt>Lorem Ipsum</prompt>
</div>


  <style type="text/css">
  
    prompt {
      color: #cc6666;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You don't seem to have anything in your CSS that would set the border color, and the rules you have set seem to work fine

Comment: Border properties in the bootstrap css file have !important on them so to colour the border yourself just put your rule below the bootstrap css file and also use the !important declaration e.g. `border-color: goldenrod !important;`

Comment: Thanks, adam: that's it! Adding the following snippet to the CSS did the trick, thank you!
.border-primary{
      --bs-border-opacity: 1;
      border-color: #cc6666 !important;
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have integrated Adam's proposal into the code snippet above.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="border rounded border-primary">
  <prompt>Lorem Ipsum</prompt>
</div>


  <style type="text/css">
  
    prompt {
      color: #cc6666;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
 
    .border-primary{ 
      --bs-border-opacity: 1; 
      border-color: #cc6666 !important; }
    
    
  </style>
</body>

</html>
```